# Get post details with pure javascript ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

I can get post details (Title, thumbnail src...) with jquery ajax. But i need get them with pure javascript. Because i am making ajax tooltip.

[Here](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip) is framework. (Check 3. example)

```
<img src="<?php echo m_thumbnail(); ?>" onmouseover="tooltip.ajax(this, 'help/tip1.txt')" >
```

How i can get post details with this example?

```
<img src="<?php echo m_thumbnail(); ?>" onmouseover="tooltip.ajax(this, '<?php echo the_title(); ?>')" >
```

Not works.

Comment: If you already know which post you're fetching, why bother with AJAX? Instead, add the title or tooltip as a data attribute. This will be significantly faster by orders of magnitude, and save waiting for the request to go to the remote server. If you really must do that though, use the REST API endpoints

Comment: Option 2 in the framework docs you linked to would also be significantly faster/more reliable than AJAX. Also keep in mind that people on phones and tablets may not see the same behaviour if it works at all

Comment: I guess, i will use non ajax version. It is more simple.

Comment: If in the tooltip, you just want to display the post title, then it's easier and simpler to use the first option: `tooltip.pop( this, '<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>' )`, instead of the `tooltip.ajax()`.